# Set/Remove for multidimentional array in symfony/httpfoundation

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm using httpfoundation https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation

I am replacing all `$_SESSION`s with this.

I.e.

`$_SESSION['user'] = 'foo'` becomes `$this->Session->set('user', 'foo');`
Using the session class.

---

I am having problems using this with multidimentional arrays.

I can get data okay by doing this:

```
$this->Session->get('user')['group']['id']
```

However when I want to set/remove a deep array to a value I have no way of doing so?

```
$this->Session->set(array('user' => array('group' => 'id')), 200); // Errors

$this->Session->remove(array('form_data' => 'test')); // Errors
```

Surely there is a clean way of doing this? I don't think it's even possible to set a deep array value using this httpfoundation session jargon.

These seems to be the only methods I can use:

```
all()
keys()
replace()
add()
get()
set()
has()
remove()
```

Shout if I'm not clear enough, cheers

---

**New methods following Matt's answer.**

Set values for testing
`$Session->set( 'test', array('test1' => array('test2' => array('test3' => 'test4') )) );`

Run methods
`$Session->setDeep('test', array('test1', 'test2', 'test3'), 'flip');`
`$Session->removeDeep('test', array('test1', 'test2', 'test3'));`

Methods are:

```
/**
 * Removes a deep variable item
 * @param string $key   Top-most array key value
 * @param array $path  one-dimentional array of path: array('user', 'group', 'id')
 */
public function removeDeep($key, $path)
{
  $new_arr = $this->get($key);
  $depth = count($path);

  switch ($depth) {
    case 1:
      return false;
      break;
    case 2:
      unset( $new_arr[$path[0]][$path[1]] );
      break;
    case 3:
      unset( $new_arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]] );
      break;
    case 4:
      unset( $new_arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]][$path[3]] );
      break;
  }
  $this->set($key, $new_arr);
}

/**
 * Sets a deep variable item
 * @param string $key   Top-most array key value
 * @param array $path  one-dimentional array of path: array('user', 'group', 'id')
 * @param mixed $value The value you will set the path to
 */
public function setDeep($key, $path, $value)
{
  $new_arr = $this->get($key);
  $depth = count($path);

  switch ($depth) {
    case 1:
      return false;
      break;
    case 2:
      $new_arr[$path[0]][$path[1]] = $value;
      break;
    case 3:
      $new_arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]] = $value;
      break;
    case 4:
      $new_arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]][$path[3]] = $value;
      break;
  }
  $this->set($key, $new_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the first parameter of `set` as the key to the top-level session array. [Pass a string as the key](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html#method_set). Instead of

```
$this->Session->set(array('user' => array('group' => 'id')), 200);
```

you want

```
$this->Session->set('user', array('group' => array('id' => 200)));
```

Keep in mind this means if you want to change an individual value you must get the full array, change the value, and set it all again:

```
$user = $session->get('user');
$user['group']['id'] = 300;
$session->set('user', $user);
```

An interesting change to the `Session` class would be to extend PHP's `ArrayObject` so you could get and set deep values just like a native array. You could always extend `Session` and do this yourself.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this will remove any other elements under 'user' though? User will have multiple array values beneath it. If I use this then it will have the group value but loose all the other values? Thank you btw I didn't realise it worked like that

Comment: Yes, exactly.  See my last edit.  You may still want a custom method to alter deep values, but you'll have to get the whole array, change values, and set the whole array.

Comment: Thanks Matt - works! I'll update my questions with new methods that do this when I'm finished. Cheers